# MLE of $\theta$ from $N(\theta+2, \theta^2)$

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from $N(\theta+2, \theta^2)$. Find the MLE of $\theta$.

I went through some work and I could not solve for $\theta$. Am I doing anything wrong?

$$L( \theta )= \prod _ { i = 1 } ^ { n } \frac { 1 } { \theta \sqrt { 2 \pi } } \exp \bigg[- \frac{( x _ { i } - \theta - 2 )^2}{2 \theta ^ { 2 }} \bigg]
= \bigg( \frac {1 } { \theta\sqrt { 2 \pi } } \bigg )^n \exp \bigg [ - \frac { \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ { n } ( x _ { i } - \theta - 2 ) ^ { 2 } } { 2 \theta ^ { 2 } }\bigg ]$$

$$\ln [ L( \theta ) ] = - n \ln ( \theta \sqrt { 2 \pi } ) - \frac { \sum _ { i= 1 } ^ { n } ( x _ { i } - \theta - 2 ) ^ { 2 } } { 2 \theta ^ { 2 } }$$

$$\frac { d \ln [ L ( \theta ) ] } { d \theta } = - \frac { n } { \theta } - \frac{2 ( - 1 ) ( 2 \theta ^ { 2 } ) \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ { n } ( x _ { i } - \theta - 2 ) - 4 \theta \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ { n } ( x _ { i } - \theta - 2 ) ^ { 2 }}{4\theta ^4}$$

$$0 = \theta \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ { n } ( x _ { i } - \theta - 2 ) + \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ { n } ( x _ { i } - \theta - 2 ) ^ { 2 } - n \theta ^ { 2 }$$

Comment: There are [different reasons](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/1273570) why links to pictures aren’t great. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Aig Question is updated. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: It looks good so far. Now you have a quadratic equation for $\theta$ that you can solve.